# Basic event stopPropagation() example - a better way of doing so?

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I've got a very very basic demo here that uses the `.stopPropagation` method. I want to just make it so that clicking on the **parent element only** runs the function, so I assumed I could use `e.stopPropagation()` as in the commented out line in the example below. However, that fails, which meant I had to apply the `stopPropagation()` method to the child element to prevent clicking on the child activating the initial click function.

Is this really the right way of doing this, or is there a better way? Something doesn't feel right here. Thanks for any help - the code is below

```js
var test = document.getElementById('test'),
    child = document.getElementById('child');

test.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  //e.stopPropagation();
  console.log('click');
});

child.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log('clicked child - is there a better way of using e.stopPropagation() ?');
});
```

```css
#test {
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}
#child {
  background: pink;
  margin-top: 5em;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id='test'>
  <div id='child'>child</div>
</div>
```

CodePen: https://codepen.io/ns91/pen/wvayqaE

Comment: I don't think this is question for codereview. Here you ask for working code. What you are looking for is `useCapture`, which defines order in which events will be captured in your code. Try playing around with passing `true` or `false` as 3rd parameter. See more at:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: I thought stackoverflow was asking for working code and stack exchange code reviews was for optimising already working code?

Comment: Do you need an event triggered when the child is clicked, or just trying to have an event triggered **only** when the parent is clicked and nothing should happen when a child element is clicked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Your Question

> Is this really the right way of doing this, or is there a better way? Something doesn't feel right here.

The term "*better*" is subjective so you can judge for yourself. Presuming there is not a need to have clicks on the child elements trigger any event handlers, one alternative is to use the CSS property [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) style. One could use the value `none`:

> **none**
> The element is never the [target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) of pointer events; however, pointer events may target its descendant elements if those descendants have pointer-events set to some other value. In these circumstances, pointer events will trigger event listeners on this parent element as appropriate on their way to/from the descendant during the event capture/[bubble](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/bubbles) phases.

```js
var test = document.getElementById('test'),
    child = document.getElementById('child');

test.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  console.log('click on parent without stopping propagation');
});
```

```css
#test {
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}
#child {
  background: pink;
  margin-top: 5em;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div id='test'>
  <div id='child'>child</div>
</div>
```